# Post list and variable to WebApi using jQuery Ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to post a list of data and a variable to WebApi using jQuery Ajax.

My clientside code is:

```
var datatopost = new Object();
for(var i=0;i<results.length;i++)
{
    datatopost["[" + i + "].NodeID"] = results[i];
}
var result;
result = grandtotal;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: createurl,
    dataType: "json",
    traditional: true,
    data: "{ 'node': '" + datatopost + "',ttl: '" + result + "'}",
    statusCode: {
        200: function () {
            alert("success");
        }
    },
    error:
        function (res) {
            alert('Error');
            $("#txtmsg").val("error" + " "
            + res.status + " " + res.statusText);
        }
});
```

My server-side code is

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostBuy([FromBody]List<Node> node, decimal ttl)
{
   //Success code here
   return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

I am receiving a bad request error in the network tab of the inspect element.

Is there any problem with my code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure, but it may be related to the "node" element in your JSON. It looks to be an object and not an array. Verify that the data is being sent properly in its JSON form.

Answer (score 0):

here is my way to post a list with some other values, I post a `JSON.stringify` string,

```
                    var o = {};
                    o.UserCode = userCode;
                    o.Role = role;
                    o.UserId = r.d;
                    o.Hotels = [];
                    $('#hotel-list li :checkbox:checked').each(function () {
                        var ctrl = $(this);
                        var h = {};
                        h.ChainId = ctrl.val();
                        h.ProjectId = ctrl.next().val();
                        h.CityId = ctrl.next().next().val();
                        o.Hotels.push(h);
                    });
                    $.post("/home/UpdateDataToDb/", { d: JSON.stringify(o) }, function (r) {

                        alert(r.Msg);
                    });
```

and my server side code is this:

```
    [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
    public JsonResult UpdateDataToDb(string d)
    {
        var jsonStr = d;

        var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QueryPostData>(jsonStr);
        //json.UserCode
        //json.Role
        //json.UserId
        foreach (var chain in json.Hotels)
        {
            //My code to handle list `Hotels`
        }
    }
```

and the `QueryPostData` is this

```
public class QueryPostData
{
    public string UserCode { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public string UserId { set; get; }
    public List<BriefChain> Hotels { get; set; }
}

public class BriefChain
{
    public string ChainId { get; set; }
    public string ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string CityId { get; set; }
}
```